# WindowLeaked: .MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

Tags: android

This happens to me when in my app when I rotate my phone after I tap the menu key/button, on the phone, (the button on the left of the home button on the device) to show the small settings dialog.

I've google a lot about this issue and I understand that I need to close/dismiss this dialog when my Activity is destroyed (`onDestroy()`). The problem is I don't know how I can accomplish this.

The even more weird thing is if I tap on the settings button on the action bar of my app to show the small settings dialog and I rotate the device no exception in generated. The exception only occurs if I used the device's menu button.

Here's the menu key/button I'm talking about:

[image]

Here is my app after I tap the menu key and the small settings dialog pops up, here if I rotate the device the exception is generated:

[image]

Here is the device after the exception been generated, AKA, after rotating the device from the previous image:

[image]

I'm running android 4.4.2 CyanogenMod.

Here is the code I think may be related to this issue:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_menu_settings)
        {
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
//          settingsFragment.setHttpService(appService);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, settingsFragment).addToBackStack("Settings").commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        Log.d(TAG, "Butao do menu");
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged - Activity");
    }
```

And I tried calling the `closeOptionsMenu()` method on the `onDestroy()` but to no success.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        closeOptionsMenu();
    }
```

Here is this stack trace:

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.my.package.design.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41865120 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-399,84} that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:725)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanelsAfterRestore(PhoneWindow.java:1899)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.access$2200(PhoneWindow.java:128)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onAttachedToWindow(PhoneWindow.java:2939)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12592)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2458)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1217)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**------------------ EDIT --------------------------**
Here's my full MainActivity.class code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String hello = "hello";

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";

//  private final MainLooperSpy mainLooperSpy = new MainLooperSpy();

    private boolean isBound = false;
    private RetainedFragment retainedFragment;
    private WebService webService;

    // Get application context
    final Context appContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext();

    // Menu item tittle
    private static final String MENU_TITTLE = "Select an Item";

    // Within which the entire activity is enclosed
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

    List<DrawerItem> dataList;


    // Title of the action bar
    String mTitle="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webService = ApplicationContextProvider.getWebService();

        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Contacts")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Contact List", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Duplicates", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Similares", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Http Server"));// adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Configuration", R.drawable.ic_action_search));

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Backups")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Local Backups", R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud Backups", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item, dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mTitle = getTitle().toString();


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

            // Called when drawer is closed
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
            {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            // Called when a drawer is opened
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
            {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(MENU_TITTLE);
            }
        };

        // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);



        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_list));

        // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) 
                {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            }
        });

        // Set the App icon has up button
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
            if (dataList.get(0).isSpinner() & dataList.get(1).getTitle() != null) 
            {
                selectItem(3); // 2
            } 
            else if (dataList.get(0).getTitle() != null) 
            {
                selectItem(1);
            } 
            else 
            {
                selectItem(0);
            }
        }

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        retainedFragment = (RetainedFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

        if (retainedFragment == null) 
        {
            retainedFragment = new RetainedFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(retainedFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
        }


    } // end onCreate()


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    /** Handling the touch event of app icon and settings icon */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_menu_settings)
        {
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
//          settingsFragment.setHttpService(appService);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, settingsFragment).addToBackStack("Settings").commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        Log.d(TAG, "Butao do menu");
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged - Activity");
    }


    public void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {

        case 2:
            fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ContactMenuFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new ContactMenuFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new HttpMenuFragment();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new SlidingFragment();
            break;
        case 9:
            fragment = new SlidingFragment();
            break;
        case 10:
            fragment = new SlidingFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(position).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }


    // Bind to the service
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        if(webService.isStarted() == false)
        {
            webService.startServer(appContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        if(webService.isStarted() == true)
        {
            webService.stopServer();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop - Activity");
//      mainLooperSpy.dumpQueue();
    }


    // Check whether the http server is set to run at startup or not
    // From the preferences settings
    public boolean isServerSetToRunAtStartUp()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        if(sharedPreferences.contains(SettingsFragment.HTTP_RUN_AT_STARTUP))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Key found!");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Key does not exist!");
        }

        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SettingsFragment.HTTP_RUN_AT_STARTUP, false) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SettingsFragment.HTTP_RUN_AT_STARTUP, false) == true)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "isServerSetToRunAtStartUp - deu verdadeiro");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
        Log.d(TAG, "onUserLeaveHint - Activity");
//      mainLooperSpy.dumpQueue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        Log.d(TAG, "onUserInteraction - Activity");
//      mainLooperSpy.dumpQueue();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause - Activity");
//      mainLooperSpy.dumpQueue();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        closeOptionsMenu();
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState - Activity");
//      mainLooperSpy.dumpQueue();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume - Activity");
//      mainLooperSpy.dumpQueue();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        closeOptionsMenu();
        super.onDestroy();
//      closeOptionsMenu();

        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy - Activity");

        webService.stopServer();
//      mainLooperSpy.dumpQueue();
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you call the `closeOptionsMenu()` *before* `super.onDestroy()`?

Comment: 323go is right.  do it before the super call.

Comment: @323go I've changed it but still causes the exception

Comment: Then post more code. Do you have any `static` members there?

Comment: @323go check my edited question for full code. Thanks

Comment: @petey thanks but it didn't work, please see my edited question for full code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your stack trace, it states that  the window leak occurs at line 725 of your PhoneWindow class. The error is occurring because you are attempting to add a new view to a window that has changed or has been removed or has not been initialized yet. make sure your layouts are established and stable before adding a view or changing a view within that layout.